# Laravel Sanctum, can't php artisan migrate because of existing users table

Tags: authentication, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to use Sanctum for Authentication on my app, I have an existing Database, I have my models and my controllers, when I follow the steps to Create the table for tokens and possibly the additional columns in the users table, with PHP artisan migrate, it shows this error.

I know what it means, the users table already exists, but is there a way to keep my table and use this command only to add the missing parts? (the tokens table and the columns)?

Here is the error :

> C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New_backend\pfa>php artisan migrate
> Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
>
> at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New_backend\pfa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:685
> 681▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 682▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 683▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 684▕         catch (Exception $e) {
> ➜ 685▕             throw new QueryException(
> 686▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 687▕             );
> 688▕         }
> 689▕
>
> 1   C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New_backend\pfa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:478
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists")
>
> 2   C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New_backend\pfa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:478
> PDOStatement::execute()

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run this command that drops all the tables and then recreates them after:

```
  php artisan migrate:fresh
```

If you want to make a data seeder later, add the argument --seed at the end:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

[The Laravel documentation about migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#drop-all-tables-migrate)